# How to show an image while vimeo video is loading?

Tags: jquery, video, background, vimeo

I'm wondering how to show an image (not thumnail from video) while the vimeo video is loading?

I'm currently using the vimeo embed full screen code and it works great as a background video header. However, I feel like it takes a little long to load and would like to show an image first while it's loading. Any help would be appreciated.

My current code is below:

```
<div class="hero-image ">
<div class="flex-video widescreen vimeo">
 <span id="insertVimeoHeader" class=""> </span>
  <div class="hero-text" >
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<a href="#recent-videos" style="" class="button MEDIUM smooth">VIEW OUR 
WORK</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I load the vimeo iframe with jquery:

```
$('#insertVimeoHeader').html('<iframe 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/198265583?background=1" width="100%" 
height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen 
allowfullscreen ></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a background image on the container i am embedding in. That way you see the image until the player is loaded. Make sure your embeded video fills out this container.

Note that my example is for a fullscreen background video

```css
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/870/640/320");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="embed-container">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&background=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```